# BeautifulSoup Not Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, python-requests

Good day,

I used BeautifulSoup to scrape the content from a website(e.g, Times of India). I need the content from a particular div class, My code -

```
import feedparser
import requests
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url ="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/no-problem-talking-to-pakistan-but-terroristan-s-jaishankar/articleshow/71287775.cms"
r = requests.get(url,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
print(url)
body=[]
try:
     for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "_3WlLe clearfix  "}):
         print(i)
except:
     continue
```

This code works fine everytime in my computer. But, when I run this code in google colab or in my friends laptop, it does not works everytime. It prints the content at one call and, prints nothing in another call(same url).

My computer info:
Running in jupyter notebook (python version - 3.7.3) 
I checked that my friends laptop has same version of python and, also installed all libraries.

It is weird, that the code works fine in my computer and not in others.
Did, I miss anything
what to do..any help 
Thank you

Comment: is that the exact class ? or its contained?

Comment: i donot understand - contained. the div class is same in the website